# CascadingDropDown Error - 'options' is null or not an object

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

I have five `DropDownList`s linked together with the `CascadingDropDown` AJAX control. When it's running locally, they work fine. However when running on the production server over the internet, I get this error every time I select a new item:

```
'options' is null or not an object
```

Debugging this shows the function that's causing it (it's JS from the `CascadingDropDown` control):

```
_clearItems : function() {
    /// <summary>
    /// Clear the items from the drop down
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns />

    var e = this.get_element();
    while (0 < e.options.length) {
        e.remove(0);
    }
},
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why it's doing this? I suspect it's because it takes longer to load the items over the internet and somehow this is affect the control?

I'm running .NET 3.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: var e = this.get_element();  after you execute this, is e null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure drop down list has autopostback = "false".autopostback = "true" was causing the problem for me.
- Fahad